# Would it be possible to change this bash loop into a case statement?

Tags: bash, loops, switch-statement

I work at  a helpdesk, and I use this script to look up info I need all the time at my job. 
This saves me a bit of time, and it has been a great learning experience. I am pretty new to scripting, and any feedback about this script will be well received.  What I would really like help with is this loop.

General Feedback welcome also.

```
# If more than one member in Array Ask for user input.
if [[ ${tLen} -gt '1' ]]; then
  for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
  do
    # adding one so user selection starts at 1
    # gobble up everything up to last back slash.
    echo "$(($i + 1 ))) ${arr[$i]##*/}"
  done
```

Would it be possible to turn this into a case statement, to protect against erroneous user input? Or another way to handle erroneous user input would be great also.  Thanks in advance for any input!

```
#!/bin/bash   

# Asking for serial number
echo -e "Enter serial number:"
read SerialNumber
SerialNumberCount=${#SerialNumber}
if [[ ${SerialNumberCount} > "11" ]]; then
  # If Serial is 12 or more characters, set the ModelSerial to four digits
  ModelSerial=$(echo $SerialNumber|awk '{ print substr( $0, length($0) - 3, length($0) ) }')
else
  # Set serial to three characters
  ModelSerial=$(echo $SerialNumber|awk '{ print substr( $0, length($0) - 2, length($0) ) }')
fi
# Set ModelURL based on length of Serial number   

# Creating temp dir/file trap for parsing html
TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}
temporary_dir=$(mktemp -d "$TMPDIR/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") || { echo "ERROR creating a temporary file" >&2; exit 1; }
trap 'rm -rf "$temporary_dir"' 0
trap 'exit 2' 1 2 3 15
temp="$temporary_dir/$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM"   

# First downloaded html page
lookupUrl=$(echo "http://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=${ModelSerial}")
curl -s -o $temp -L $lookupUrl    

# Parsing partial links 
webRslt=$(cat $temp |   grep -o '<a href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' |   sed -e 's/^<a href=["'"'"']//' -e 's/["'"'"']$//'|grep /systems* |grep ".html" )   

# Creating Array of partial links
arr=($webRslt)    

# Length of Array
tLen=${#arr[@]}   

# If more than one member in Array Ask for user input.
if [[ ${tLen} -gt '1' ]]; then
  for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
  do
    # adding one so user selection starts at 1
    # gobble up everything up to last back slash.
    echo "$(($i + 1 ))) ${arr[$i]##*/}"
  done

  # Ask user for input 
  printf "\n"
  echo "Please enter 1-${tLen} --> "
  read -r sel
  # Subtracting one from selection for correct Array member
  ArraySel=$((sel - 1)) 
  curl  "${arr["$ArraySel"]/#/http://everymac.com}" -s -o "$temp"
else
  # If array only has one member do this... 
  curl  "${arr[0]/#/http://everymac.com}" -s -o "$temp"
fi
clear   

# Parsing html for screen printing 
get_value() { perl -nE 'say $1 if m!>\Q'"$1"'\E</td>\s*<td[^>]+>([^<]+)<!' <"$temp"; }
VAR1=$(get_value "Apple Model No:")
VAR2=$(get_value "Apple Order No:")
VAR3=$(get_value "Model ID:")
VAR4=$(get_value "Processor Speed:")
VAR5=$(get_value "Standard RAM:")
VAR6=$(get_value "Maximum RAM:")
VAR7=$(get_value "RAM Type:")
VAR8=$(get_value "Pre-Installed MacOS:")
VAR9=$(get_value "Maximum MacOS:")
VAR10=$(get_value "Minimum Windows:")
VAR11=$(get_value "Maximum Windows:")
VAR12=$(get_value "Original Price (US):")
tput setaf 2
printf "\033[1mRam & Apple Model Information Information (experimental beta)\033[m\n\n"
printf "Apple Model No:\t\\t\033[1m$VAR1\033[m\n"
printf "Apple Order No::\t\033[1m$VAR2\033[m\n"
printf "Model ID:\t\\t\033[1m$VAR3\033[m\n"
printf "Processor Speed:\t\033[1m$VAR4\033[m\n"
printf "Standard RAM:\t\\t\033[1m$VAR5\033[m\n"
printf "Maximum RAM:\t\\t\033[1m$VAR6\033[m\n"
printf "RAM Type:\t\\t\033[1m$VAR7\033[m\n"
printf "Pre-Installed MacOS:\t\033[1m$VAR8\033[m\n"
printf "Maximum MacOS::\t\t\033[1m$VAR9\033[m\n"
printf "Minimum Windows:\t\033[1m$VAR10\033[m\n"
printf "Maximum Windows:\t\033[1m$VAR11\033[m\n"
printf "Original Price (US):\t\033[1m$VAR12\033[m\n"
printf "\n\n"
printf "See URL below for more details."
printf "\n\n"   

# Print page that is being parsed on  screen. 
if [[ ${tLen} -gt '1'  ]]; then
  tput setaf 2
  echo "${arr[$ArraySel]/#/http://everymac.com}"
else
  tput setaf 2
  echo "${arr[0]/#/http://everymac.com}"
fi
printf "\n\n"
```

Comment: I recommend you use double-quotes in more places. Unquoted parameter expansions undergo word splitting and filename expansion, which is rarely what anyone wants. (But funnily enough, in some of the places that you do use double-quotes, I think single-quotes would be more appropriate. It's true that `"\n"` is a backslash followed by `n`, but `'\n'` is a more straightforward way to express that.)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't completely understand your question; but it sounds like what you need is the `select` command (described in [§3.2.4.2 "Conditional Constructs" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)), which presents a menu of numbered items for users to select from. In your case, you might write:

```
if (( ${#arr[@]} == 1 )) ; then
    url="${arr[0]}"
else
    # present the user with all elements of the array, numbered,
    # and store the selected element in $url:
    select url in "${arr[@]}" ; do break ; done
fi
curl "${url/#/http://everymac.com}" -s -o "$temp"
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant... Thank you. I will test this when I get a chance.  I think I was mixing up my a term from another programming class... lol